# Baking should happen to image with image buffer

Tags: uv, baking, error, normal-map

I'm trying to bake Normals from Multires on a model, but lately I've only been getting the error "Baking should happen to image with image buffer". I can bake multires on a new blender file, but if I import my FBX and try to bake normals I get the above error so I think there is something up with the model. The model has multiple UVs and Shape Keys but it was working at one point when that was also the case.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Edit: the problem still occurs even if I clear all UVs and SKs and regenerate a new UV.

Comment: Try saving the image in blender or to a file

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately that doesn't worth either, I've tried not saving, packing in blender and external files and they all do the same thing. The same thing happens even in a fresh blender file (when I export the original FBX)

Comment: Do you use UDIMs? https://blenderartists.org/t/baking-image-buffer/1294362

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of error happens in three cases :

1. texture (you trying to bake on) was moved to another folder
2. texture was deleted
3. ".blend" file itself was moved (while texture was NOT)

__

So, basically, that error means: "Path to the texture is not valid anymore"

To fix this:

just press the "folder icon" on your texture node and set a new path to the texture.

So simple.